# I kind of want to do (redo, actually) math

Tags: math, nlp

I want to redo my mathematics, since I honestly feel deprived. I'm a pre-final year Computer Engg (!) student in India. I eventually want to be a mathematically mature (yeah, that's how I wanna phrase it!) PROGRAMMER (in Machine Learning, NLP)! A Genuine request.

An example of kind of maturity I expect will be clear by following example:
    Someone asks me to write a C program to calculate the sum of the squares of the first 100 odd natural numbers. Naturally my answer would go something like:

```
for(i=0,sum=0;i<100;i++)
{
    sum += square(2*i+1);
}
```

BUT, one of my 'mathematically mature' friend came up with this (yeah this thing was actually asked!)

```
∑(2n+1)² = ∑ (4n² + 4n + 1)= ...SO ON.
```

Came up with a formula & put `100` for `n` & he was done in a single C line.

I couldn't think of such a thing, until he did. So, I think I've made things a little simpler for you to get my intention of asking this question.

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking something along the lines of: 'What resources are available that will help me increase my mathematical knowledge?' If so, you could make your question clearer by editing it to include an explicit request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) is a fun way for computer programmers to find out more about maths. Try working through the first few problems in the language of your choice. Solving a problem will unlock discussion and sometimes a PDF explaining the mathematical background.

For stuff that's specifically relevant to machine learning and NLP, you might want to check out some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2233435/11575).

Answer (score 0):

Maths is definitely a useful thing to have a good working knowledge of for programming. I'm not entirely sure what your request is though?